# apache RewriteRule is sending requests twice

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to change the url for PHP files using the below apache rewrite rule

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(php)$
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost.weebsy1.com:90/$1 [R=307,L]`

The problem with this rule is that its sending all the ajax requests twice, first request status come 307 and the next is getting cancelled in some browsers. Like in the below screenshot of ajaxRequests:

[image]

Please help me understand whats going wrong in the rewrite rule. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, obviously you have two requests: the first hits your rewrite rule, gets responded to with the http status 307, the next hits the URL you rewrite to.

Comment: ok, what would be the reason the next request is getting cancelled, this works fine in chrome and mozilla, the issue is in safari.

Comment: and how can I avoid 2 requests from being sent?

Comment: You can't with that setup, _unless_ the client already knows the final URL and requests that directly without relying on the redirection.

Comment: Well, obviously you could do an _internal_ rewriting using the internal proxy module, so that the client does not need to do anything.

Comment: ok, could you please help with any link describing internal proxy module

Comment: Well, I suggest you take a look at the official documentation which should be the first thing you read about the tools you are trying to use anyway. It is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can use a server internal rewriting in combination with the server side proxy module to prevent that two requests are sent:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(php)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.com:90/$1 [P,END]
```

If you are using a very old version of the apache http server you may have to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag.

For the above to work some preconditions have to be fulfilled:

- the rewrite module has to be enabled, obviously
- the proxy module has to be enabled

The above rule should work in the host configuration section *and* in `.htaccess` style dynamic configuration files likewise.

---

An alternative would be to use *only* the proxy module:

```
<LocationMatch ^/(.*\.php)$>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://example.com:90/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://example.com:90/ 
</LocationMatch>
```

This approach only works in the http servers host configuration, *not* in dynamic configuration files.

---

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).